# SSIS Split rows in a flatfile using conditional split or script

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssis, etl

I'm new to SSIS, your idea or solution is greatly appreciated.

I have a flat file with the first row as the file details(not the header). The second row onwards is the actual data.

**Data description**

First-row format= Supplier_name, Date, number of records in the file
eg:

> Supplier_name^06022017^3
>   ID1^Member1^NEW YORK^050117^50.00^GENERAL^ANC
>   ID2^Member2^FLORIDA^050517^50.00^MOBILE^ANC
>   ID3^Member3^SEATTLE^050517^80.00^MOBILE^ANC
>   EOF

**Problem**

Using SSIS I want to split the First row into output1 and second row onwards into output2.

With the help of conditional split, I thought I can do this. But I'm not sure what condition to give in order to split the rows. Should I try with multicast?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all. Here is an alternative solution

I used a script component in SSIS to do this.

**Step1:** Create a variable called RowNumber.

**Step2:** Then add a script component which will add an additional column and increments row numbers.

SSIS Script component

```
 private int m_rowNumber;
public override void PreExecute()
{
    base.PreExecute();
    m_rowNumber = 0;
}

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    m_rowNumber++;
    Row.RowNumber = m_rowNumber;
}
```

**Step3:** Use the output of Script component as the input of conditional split and create a condition with RowNumber == 1.

The Multicast will split the data accordingly.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would handle this by using a script task (BEFORE the dataflow) to read the first row and do whatever you want with it.

Then in the dataflow task, I would set the flat file source to ignore the first row and import the second row on as data.

Answer (score 0):

I would first make sure that you have the correct number of columns in your Flat File Connection:
Edit the Flat File Connection -> Advanced Tab press the New button to add columns. In your example you should have 7, Column 0 to Column 6.

Now add a conditional split and ass two case statements:

```
Output Name      Condition
HeaderRow        [Column 0] == "Supplier_Name"
DetailRow        [Column 0] != "Supplier_Name"
```

Now route these to the Output 1 and Output 2

Comment: This will work but if the Supplier_Name varies from file to file. It would be difficult to handle

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Tab Allerman's answer.

For our project, we used a power shell script component inside an `Execute process task` which runs a simple power shell command to grab the first line of the file.

See this [MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssis/2017/01/26/run-powershell-scripts-in-ssis/) on how to run power shell script.

Power shell script to get the first line

```
Get-Content C:\foo\yourfolderpath\yourfilename.txt -First 1
```

This note only helps in case like yours, but generically helps in avoiding processing large files (in GBs and upwards) which have incorrect header. This simple power shell executes in milliseconds as opposed to most of the processes/scripts which will require to load a full file into memory, slowing things down.